# Extending the type scheme for Burks/Warren/Wright machine to handle operators on functions?

Tags: logic, typing

Some background: Burks, Warren and Wright published a description of simple interpreter for a Logic Machine for unparenthesized Lukasiewicz notation ([paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1954-08-046/), [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22366141/how-to-understand-the-f-function-in-burks-warren-wrights-lukasiewicz-logic-mach), [c implementation](https://gist.github.com/luser-dr00g/9542998), [postscript implementation](https://gist.github.com/luser-dr00g/9519896)) which was heavily cited in Kenneth Iverson's 1962 classic [A Programming Language](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/apl/Physics%20in%20APL2/APROGRAMMING%20LANGUAGE/view).

Within there is an elegant system of typing by associating integer *weight* to variables, literals, and functions, which allows a simple max_weight/length test for well-formedness (ready for reduction), as well as a simple formula to convert the weight into the *degree* or arity of the function. Specifically, variables and literals are given weight=1, and unary functions are given weight=0, and binary functions are given weight=-1. For a function (w<1), its degree *d* is *1-w*.

What I'd like to do, and I'm not sure how to go about it, is to add APL's *operator* type to the mix. But it would seem that I need a very weird kind of number, that can by simple arithmetic yield the *function arity* and yield the correct positive (minimum, ie. 1) weight for a complete well-formed formula.

For the extended language, I'm adding integers 0-9 as well as variables a-z, binary + and -, and unary < "box" and > "unbox", and the monadic operator / "reduce". Also, we'll use infix syntax with right-to-left evaluation, like APL.

So for the very simple formula "0+4", we encounter

```
0  literal, w=1
0+  function, w=-1, sum of weights=0,  function degree=1-w=2
0+4  literal, w=1, sum of weights=1 <--complete wff
```

Now the problem happens when I try to add an operator, it needs to counterbalance the weight of its associated functions, thus it should be positive, but it shouldn't ever create a condition of "false positive", so it also needs to be *further* from positive. Perhaps another dimension, or a second field of the type descriptor?

For "+/ab", the sequence of discovery is

```
+  function, w=-1, function degree=1-w=2
+/  operator w=1??  sum of weights=0
+/a  variable, w=1, sum of weights=1 <-- false positive.
+/ab  variable w=1, sum of weights=2, yet I want this to sum to 1.
```

Is there a better way that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Hmmmm. quaternions???

Comment: This Iverson paper appears to use *valence* where Burks et al. say *degree*. http://www.jsoftware.com/papers/APLOperators.htm